# Asterisk (Elastix 4.0.0) Misc Destination Call Hangup Issue

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, elastix

i'm using Asterisk (Elastix 4.0.0) as my VoIP Server.
I'm using TDM2400P card as my DAHDI trunk

i set Misc Destination to outside mobile number..
calls are forwarding correctly.but when i hangup from outside my server dose not hangup the telephone line.

this is call flow chart [call flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SpYK.jpg)

- incoming call through TDM2400P
- it forward to mobile number through TDM2400P

how can i fix this issue.
thank you.

Comment: You should setup your card correctly acordinly to your privider

Comment: can you enplane it please??

Comment: There are no way determine why your card not detecting hangup based on provided data. This question is NOT programming question and should be removed from SO.

Comment: this is my chan_dahdi.conf file  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IWxzhTfRBsz45aX6-Dcy4YIKrwRLGBQ1K1MJm6IMJUM/edit?usp=sharing

i enable busydetect facility...
is there any other configurations??

@arheops yes this is not a programming question..i need to know how to configure this system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably misinterpreting the tones your TELCO sends via the POTS line. Make sure the indications.conf file has the right configuration for your country.